# Confused with this async thunk

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

```
export const loginSuccess = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/loginSuccess",
  async (user: User) => {
    const res = await api
      .post(
        "/auth/loginSuccess",
        { user },
        {
          withCredentials: true,
        }
      )
      .then((res: any) => {
        setAxiosToken(res.data.token);
        saveToken(res.data.token);
        return { ...res.data.data, token: res.data.token };
      });

    return res;
  }
);
```

There are 2 return statements at the end so I am confused about which return value the fulfilled reducer will get. The code is written by someone else that's why I want to understand it.

Comment: is `api` here referring to `axios`?

I'm not posting this as an answer - I'd want to actually run the code first to double check what I'm saying, but the second return here is the one that is returned from the thunk (there is no reducer in play here, unless they have changed the defintions, which could have happened).

The first return - from inside the `then` is actually assigned to the outer const `res` variable, so they are returning the 'same' thing.

Comment: Regarding the code - there are several problems that I would personally tidy up.
1. Reusing the variable name `res` is confusing.
2. Mixing promises with `then` and async await is also a bit confusing. I'm pretty sure you can move the content of the then into the main function. (I would have to check the by running the code before commiting the change though)
3, `setAxiosToken` and `saveToken` look like they could be better places somewhere else. I believe axios has some custom middleware extension points that are meant for this sort of thing. But again, I'd have to review that.

Comment: And last point to what this function returns - it returns the following:

`{ ...res.data.data, token: res.data.token }`

where res here is the response from the api call. The `data.data` object is then spread into a new object, and data.token is then assigned directly to the `token` property of that new object.

Comment: I got the answer though i was just confused with the 2 return statements only. And yes api refers to axios and  the fullfilled action overrites the state with the payload

Comment: Oh good - glad It cleared it up, I'll make that an anwser. It has been over a year since I last used redux properly. And there were weren't using thunks so much. But if I remember correctly, I have always dispatched a second normal action from within the thunk itself, in order to modify the state. But if it works for you like this then good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second return statement is the one which will return from your function.

The first is actually returning from the `then` function of the promise that `axios` returns.

This is made a little bit confusing by using the same name for the `res` variable in the thunk function, and for the response variable that is passed to the `then` function.

But what you will receive back is the object generated in this line of code:

```
{ ...res.data.data, token: res.data.token }
```

Where `res.data.data` is spread into a new object, and `res.data.token` is assigned to the token property of that object.